# Why aren't createjs DOMElements positioned correctly at top left of the canvas like all other objects?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, createjs

(As per the title)

If you create an HTML button and place it on the canvas with createjs:

```
var html = document.createElement('input');
html.type = 'button';
html.id = 'testing button';
html.value = 'test';
var DOMElement = new createjs.DOMElement(html);

var target = document.getElementById(<name of a div in your HTML>);

target.appendChild(html);

//returns the first canvas element seen in the page
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", function(event) {
    stage.update(event);
});

stage.addChild(DOMElement);
stage.update();
```

The button will appear **outside** of the canvas. This is mostly likely an artifact of the HTML and CSS (I don't have the background to say why this is); Instead of at the default position on the stage (0, 0), the top left, like all other createjs DisplayObjects.

Comment: Isn't DOMElement for the EaselJS module not CreateJS. I doubt it's supposed to put an HTML button on your canvas.

Comment: Here you go: ["A DOMElement allows you to associate a HTMLElement with the display list."](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DOMElement.html)

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be related to CSS styling. As a simple addition of two styling options has the default position of the button set at the top left (0, 0) as we expect:

```
var html = document.createElement('input');
html.type = 'button';
html.id = 'testing button';
html.value = 'test';
html.style.top = 0; // <--
html.style.left = 0; // <--
```

These properties according to MDN, determine position relative to the top and left margins:

> For absolutely positioned elements (those with position: absolute or
>   position: fixed), it specifies the distance between the top / left
>   margin edge of the element and the top / left edge of its containing
>   block.

Source: [Top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) & [Left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left).

If someone could chime in for the reason as to this behavior and a little more detail that would be great, as I said I simple don't have the background in CSS or HTML to say why.